# Is it possible for a function $f(x+a)$ to have a regular Taylor series expansion centered around $a$ instead of $-a$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a question, but I think there's a typo in part (b).
If we've got function $f(x+a)$, shouldn't the series end up being centered around $-a$, and not $a$?
I've worked it out myself and I'm getting $f(-a)$, not $f(0)$ inside the sigma expression for part $(b)$.

This is the question below:

[image]

### Edit

The next part of the question was:

[image]

Comment: Well from the definition of $g(x)$ we get for instance $g(0) = f(a)$ which matches the sum given in part (b). Similarly $g'(0) = f'(a)$ and so on. So in the expression given in (i) we should first replace $f$ by $g$ to find the expansion for $g$. Then apply $g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(a)$

Comment: but how do we go from  g(n)(0)=f(n)(a) to  g(n)(x)=f(n)(x)?

Comment: I poster an answer, hopefully that will clear it up.

Comment: @user961627 please use Latex otherwise the formatting is horrible and even a good question can not be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n
$$
by the expression in part (i). Now, by $g(x)=f(x+a)$ and the chain rule we have $g'(x)=f'(x+a) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x+a)=f'(x+a)$ and similarly for higher order derivatives. In particular we have $g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0+a)=f^{(n)}(a)$. Thus
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}x^n,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Oh I see the connection now! Thank you!

Comment: If that's how simple the proof is, then I guess to solve part (c) (I just added an edit), would I be correct in simply making the connection that that since g(x) is as we showed it to be in (b), then since f(x) = g(x-a), then we can arrive at (c), just by substituting x with (x-a) in the (b) formula?